# docker-compose up invalid mode /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ - cannot create container for service database

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have to use docker-compose up to start a database. Everything we needed for that is already given and it works for my partners. Meanwhile I have the following problem. (I'm using Mac OS Catalina btw)
Every time I try to use docker-compose up the following error occurs

> docker-compose up
>
> Creating ziegel24_database_1 ... error
>
> ERROR: for ziegel24_database_1  Cannot create container for service database: invalid mode: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
>
> ERROR: for database  Cannot create container for service database: invalid mode: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

the docker-compose.yml is the following

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/db/entrypoint:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=geheim"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=Ziegel24"
```

I have already checked if my docker compose and engine are the correct version which they are. (Mysql is on a newer version but since docker creates a new database it would pull the needed sql version I was told)

I also have tried to locate the said **docker-entrypoint-initdb.d** directory but even running find on my whole computer didn't give results, so I guess the whole directory is not there?

Is there any way to download it manually or does it come in a package I mistakenly didn't install?

**EDIT**
I've realised the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d shouldn't be on my computer anyway, but in the mysql:5.7 image. I still don't know what the exact error is and how to fix it but yeah that's new.

Since I didn't find any help when I searched my error I came here for help.

Comment: can you show the content of `/mysql/db/entrypoint`? what you are trying to run here?

Comment: there is a ```ziegel24.sql.gz``` file there.

the whole thing should just start a database as far as I know

Answer (score 3):

The [short syntax for volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) is `(HOST:CONTAINER)` or `(HOST:CONTAINER:ro)` if access mode is specified.
If the host path contains a colon (`:`) `CONTAINER` is interpreted as access mode.

In your case `./mysql/db/entrypoint` is a relative path and docker expands it to full path. If this full path contains a colon, `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` is considered the access mode which is obviously invalid (allowed values are `ro` and `rw`), hence the error.

This might not be your case but I could reproduce the behaviour above with Docker version 18.04.0-ce, build 3d479c0 and docker-compose version 1.21.0, build 5920eb0 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The colon scenario happened to me. TY

Comment: for me it was more subtle: "~/.ssh:/root/ssh:ro ". The space at the end is printed into an error message, but one has to use some text editor to see it.